# Apache2 multiple servers

Tags: 14.04, server

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to add multiple LAMP server.
How can I do this.
I tried a lot of things but it doesn't work... I'm new in Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using Apache 2.4.

You have to create a virtual host for every server in directory `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

A sample file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName server1.com

   <Directory "/any-path/server1">
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

   DocumentRoot /any-path/server1

</VirtualHost>
```

Save this as `s1.conf` and make a second one `s2.conf`. Note that apache 2.4 requires the file extension to be `.conf`.

Make the directories:

```
mkdir /any-path/server1
mkdir /any-path/server2
```

Copy the default index.html:

```
cp /var/www/html/index.html /any-path/server1
cp /var/www/html/index.html /any-path/server2
```

Modify them, so you can see which server you are accessing:

```
nano /any-path/server1/index.html
nano /any-path/server2/index.html
```

If you now run `service apache2 restart`, then both sites should become active.

You can test that by adding entries to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
192.168.12.165  server1.com
192.168.12.165  server2.com
```

But replace the IP address with the IP address of the server.

Then point your browser to `www.server1.com` and `www.server2.com`.

Note: Normally you would create your `.conf` files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and enable/disable them using `a2ensite` and `a2dissite`, but for testing it is easier to create them in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you need is to set up some virtual hosts, to run different sites with different root directories.

try to have a look at one of the tutorial available on the internet.

google first result is
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts